# Hard Disk non-existent in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Had 2 harddisk listed under my ubuntu, one has the system and another Hitachi was just added under / as just additional drive, it was running fine for a month, under NTFS file system, i cannot see the drive in Gparted and checked physically the cables they are all tight and fitted .... noticed the temp as around 50 most of the time, not sure what happened now, has it died, or is there a way i can check ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, checking is easy.  First boot your computer to any ubuntu live CD.  Press the windows key and type DISK.  Open Disk Utility when it appears.  Select your drive, if it is even visible and attempt to determine the drive health.  In the case of hard drives with SMART, you can see what the drive says about itself.

I should probably add that although I've actually encountered Hitachi drives that weren't actually bad, of the few I've handled, most had issues.  I tend to avoid that brand.  You can buy good laptop drives used on Amazon for as little as $15 guaranteed to work but without a choice of brand.  The odds you'll wind up with a dead Hitachi is rather low.